# How to send email report FROM other than default email address?

Tags: api, email, civireport

I have a report that is sending successfully every week. Only issue is I was not able to set FROM email address for the report. It’s always sent from default email address, but I need to send from different email. Can anyone suggest how to solve this issue please? Or whether it’s even possible at all? Thanks

parameters for API call is currently like this

```
instanceId=50
format=print
sendmail=1
```

Comment: Anyone knows if it’s possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it has this feature. One possibility is make an extension and use [hook_civicrm_alterMailParams](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterMailParams) to check if the email is your report and then change the from.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I am not a developer so it would not be difficult for me to create an extension. I thought this function might have been there already.

Comment: Do you know how to make an extension? If yes, Please let me know how I can contact you.

Comment: It's a lot of reading but start here https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/

Answer (score -1):

If you own another email address, you can send mail as that address. For example:

Yahoo, Outlook, or other non-Gmail address
Your work, school, or business domain or alias, like @yourschool.edu or youralias@gmail.com
Another Gmail address